# Using QPainter with QCoreApplication

Tags: c++, qt

We have an application (QCoreApplication) that takes some images as input, does something to them, and exports them again. We now need to add some text to the images, and tried to do this with the QPainter class. It all worked well when using it in one of our other apps (using QApplication), but not in our main QCoreApplication app.

Here is the code:

```cpp
void drawTextOnImage(QImage* image, const QString& text, const QFont& font)
{
    QPainter p;
    if (!p.begin(image)) return;

    p.setFont(font);
    p.drawText(image->rect(), Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop | Qt::TextWordWrap, text);

    p.end();
}
```

The application crashes on the `drawText` line.

Any ideas?

It is a very simple text, so suggestions without using Qt will also be appreaciated.

Comment: QCoreApplication is the base class for console applications. It's just not possible to use QCoreApplication with Widgets (and either QPainter or QImage depend on the widgets). You need to use a QApplication instead.

Comment: You might try to paint rather on `QPixmap` than on a `QImage`. I.e. change your function to: `void drawTextOnImage(const QPixmap &image, const QString& text, const QFont& font)`

Comment: @markus-nm `QPainter` does not depends on widgets and it does not require a `QApplication`, but rather a `QGuiAppication`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using classes from "Qt Gui" like `QPainter`, you are supposed to use a `QGuiApplication`, not a `QCoreApplication`.

You might get lucky and be able to make some GUI stuff works while using only a `QCoreApplication`. But as you have discovered, it makes your application very brittle. Some classes like `QPixmap` will print an error message, but others will just crash.

The same is applicable with "Qt Widget": if you use a widget related class, you must use a `QApplication`.

Note that since `QApplication` inherits `QGuiApplication`, if you have a `QApplication` you can use "Qt Gui".

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to run a non-GUI application on something without a windowing system, you need, aside from creating an instance of `QGuiApplication`, to also choose an appropriate Qt platform.

For me, `offscreen` platform worked fine. I was generating images with textual elements and saving them to files on a headless Raspberry Pi. My code then was like the example below. Note that `setenv` is a POSIX function and may need a replacement on Windows, though I'm not sure whether windowless Windows is a thing at all.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QGuiApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setenv("QT_QPA_PLATFORM","offscreen",1);
    QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);

    QImage img(128,128, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    img.fill(Qt::white);
    QPainter p(&img);
    p.drawText(QPoint(0,64), "Works!");
    img.save("/tmp/test.png");
}
```